# How to tie SqlRoleProvider to "My" user table

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, security

How to tie SqlRoleProvider to "My" user table

I am using asp.net MVC and SqlRoleProvider appears to work out of the box. However I have my own users and roles. I have a user table the has all the user/personalized data. How do I tie the account controller back to my table. My table has a userID and I use that to tie other actions to a particular user.

Would be great if I could use the account controller and after the user logs in, I have their ID.

I have been looking at this but is not quite the same as asp.net mvc

https://web.archive.org/web/20210417083524/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121405-1.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the same in asp.net mvc, but we use the `SqlMembership` provider for authentication with gives us back a `MembershipUser` object.  The `MembershipUser` instance has a `ProviderUserKey` property which we map to our own user table's MemberId field (which is different to our internal UserId).

Comment: I see that, so basically after I validate the user I can get their key and use that as "my" id. Would have to tie that in when creating the user also?

Comment: I am wondering now, looking at the account controller if I can just merge the account controller in the basic asp.net MVC project with my "create" user controller method. Then I get my personalized data (address,zip,etc) and can use the ProvidersUserKey as a key between my table and the sqlMembership data.

Comment: Yeah, spot on. Good luck and glad I could help!